# How can I see all of the endpoint from swagger?

Tags: swagger, sails.js, swagger-ui

I was installed this library, I am working with `sails.js`

```
npm install sails-hook-swagger-generator --save
```

from their main website https://github.com/theoomoregbee/sails-hook-swagger-generator

I have created this file `./swagger/swagger.json`

I want to see the swagger from the browser, how can I see the endpoints?

I have in routes something like that

`'GET /api/v1/information': { action: 'actions/getinformation' },`

I can not see nothing from the browser, what is the problem?

**EDIT 1**

from their answer https://github.com/theoomoregbee/sails-hook-swagger-generator/issues/27

> you can simply change the directory you want to place the generated
> swagger json may be assets, then clone
> https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui following the instructions
> here
>
> Just simply extract the dist folder (which is needed for just the
> swagger ui) and update this line
> https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/1a95b9e9c972b95227a2976553fea988e58d7ff2/dist/index.html#L44
> to be the path to the generated swagger json within your assets folder

i dont know what should i put in that line, i am putting the path of my file swagger.json

```
/disk/team/work/proyect/swagger
```

but when i try this url in the browser
http://127.0.0.1:8080/
i am getting this [2020-09-01T19:39:35.791Z]  "GET /" Error (404): "Not found"
[2020-09-01T19:39:35.961Z]  "GET /" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
[2020-09-01T19:39:35.963Z]  "GET /" Error (404): "Not found"

Comment: Are you saying you want to see the swagger.json file or the UI on an endpoint?

Comment: @lisaah i want to see the swagger ui

Comment: As far as I can tell, that functionality is not there out of the box, you'll have to do some additional steps to generate the UI files and then setup a route to hit them. See: https://github.com/theoomoregbee/sails-hook-swagger-generator/issues/27 and https://github.com/theoomoregbee/sails-hook-swagger-generator/issues/28